# calling main thread from Runnable thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

i have implemented a Runnable interface to load the image tiles and i want to call the Main thread from this secondary thread for displaying the tiles.
can anybody tell me how to call a Main thread from a Runnable Interface thread in Java.

thanks.

Comment: It is generally good design to call other thread from main thread.

Comment: @org.life.java, what do you (and OP) mean when you say "call another thread"?

Comment: @aioobe I think OP wants to call main thread from another thread started from main. something like http://ideone.com/G8gLN

Comment: are you doing a Swing app? Do you mean to ask how to get the Event Dispatch Thread to do something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Runnable` you can use `Callable<Set<Image>>` which returns a set of loaded images. Submit this callable task to an executor, get the `Future<Set<Image>>` and wait for the loading thread to finish its job.

For example:

```
Future<Set<Image>> future =
  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Callable<Set<Image>>()
    {
      @Override
      public Set<Image> call() throws Exception
      {
        return someServiceThatLoadsImages.load();
      }
    });

try
{
  Set<Image> images = future.get();
  display(images);
} catch (Exception e)
{
  logger.error("Something bad happened", e);
}
```

Comment: . Check it now ... 7135 -> 7145 :)

Comment: +1 Like the idea too. But it depends on the task right? Here the main thread has to check if the loading is done. If you make a callback, you can callback whenever the loading has finished.

Comment: This technically works. But it obviously doesn't make sense to halt execution of one Thread and ask a singular other Thread to do all the work. Generally a pattern which uses `Future.get()` would operate over a Collection of Futures and potentially use an ExecutorService with more than a single Thread.

Comment: @TimBender That is the part that I am stuck on. How do you callback to the main thread without halting it?

Comment: @MikeV ... without halting? Well, you could do busy-waiting by constantly checking for `Future.isDone`. Or you could use a `BlockingQueue` and perform a `poll` to similarly perform busy-waiting. Or use `BlockingQueue.take` to halt until something puts a message in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "call a thread"?

You probably want to somehow "notify" the main thread that the images have been loaded. You could this by for instance letting the main thread `wait()` for the load thread to `notify()` it that the images have been loaded.

Preferably however, you should use one of the more "high-level" concurrency classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package. For instance `Callable` and `Future` as suggested by Boris Pavlović. There is a sample usage in [the documentation of `Future`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't really "call" one thread from another. What you can do is to have a queue of messages: the secondary thread would put messages onto the queue and the main thread would pick them up off the queue and process.

Comment: Yes, in Java this can be done with a BlockingQueue and calling BlockingQueue.take() or BlockingQueue.poll(). A lot of people use an ExecutorService to manage all of this.

Answer (score -1):

I think by "call the thread" the author meant some kind of callback from the working thread to the main thread to notify it about some kind of event.

There are a lot of ways to implement that kind of callback but I'd use a simple listener interface. Something like this:

```
//Interface of the listener that listens to image load events
public interface ImageLoadListener {
 void onImageLoadSuccess(ImageInformation image);
 void onImageLoadFailed(ImageInformation image);
}

//Worker thread that loads images and notifies the listener about success
public class ImageLoader implements Runnable {
 private final ImageLoadListener loadListener;
 public ImageLoader(ImageLoadListener listener) {
  this.loadListener = listener;
 }

 public void run() {
  ....
  for (each image to load) {
   ....
   if (load(image)) {
    if (loadListener != null) {
     loadListener.onImageLoadSuccess(image);
    }
   } else {
    if (loadListener != null) {
     loadListener.onImageLoadFailed(image);
    }
   }   
  }
 }
}

//Main class that creates working threads and processes loaded images
public class MainClass {
 ...

 //Main method for processing loaded image
 void showImageAfterLoad(ImageInformation information) {
  ...
 }

 //Some button that should create the worker thread
 void onSomeButtonClick() {
  //Instantiate the listener interface. If image load is successful - run showImageAfterLoad function on MainClass
  ImageLoadListener listener = new ImageLoadListener() {
   void onImageLoadSuccess(ImageInformation image) {
    MainClass.this.showImageAfterLoad(image);
   }
   void onImageLoadFailed(ImageInformation image) {
    //Do nothing
   }
  };

  //Create loader and it's thread
  ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(listener);
  new Thread(loader).start();
 }
}
```

In case you need it to be scalable then I'd recommend to swap to some implementation of Event Bus pattern. For example: http://code.google.com/p/simpleeventbus/

Event bus is generally the same thing as I wrote in my example but very scalable. Main difference is you can manage various kinds of events and register lots of listeners at once.

Comment: -1 based on the opening statement. The "callback" does not actually execute on the "main thread" in your example, but instead still on the new Thread instance that was started.

Comment: @Tim Bender: Opening statement does not have word "execute" anywhere. However, author asks for a way to "call" the thread. "Calling" can be anything starting from executing the thread as you understood it, to providing it some data so it can use it for some calculations - as I understood it.

Comment: No problem with this answer - it's more flexible (what if I want to do interim reporting, such as progress, but have other reasons to avoid SwingWorker), and is, in fact, the way I read the original question, too.  It also provides a generic Listener example without having to crawl through the millions of ActionListener samples.